# Get all names of users who have placed car orders totalling more than 40000$

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I have the following tables:

```
Cars (CarID, Colour, Price)
CarOrders(CarID, OrderID, AmountOfCars)
Orders(OrderID, UserID)
Users (UserID, Name)
```

I'd like to query:
all names of users who have placed car orders totalling more than 40000 (also considering amount, if a user buys the same car multiple times), alongside the number of these orders. The desired results format is: (Users.name, Number)

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users
JOIN (
    SELECT a.UserID, SUM(a.AmountOfCars*b.Price) total 
    FROM Orders a 
    JOIN Cars b, ON b.CarID == a.CarID, 
    GROUP BY a.UserID
) c ON c.UserID == c.UserID 
WHERE c.total > 20000
```

Comment: You shouldn't have comma before `ON` or `GROUP BY`

Comment: `Orders` doesn't have a `CarID` column, so how can you use `a.CarID`?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    U.Name,
    SUM(C.Price * CO.AmountOfCars) AS 'Price'
FROM Users U
JOIN Orders O ON U.UserID = O.UserID
JOIN CarOrders CO ON CO.OrderID = O.OrderID
JOIN Cars C ON C.CarID = CO.CarID
GROUP BY U.Name
HAVING  SUM(C.Price * CO.AmountOfCars) > 40000
```

Comment: You can avoid the repetition by using `HAVING Price > 40000`, since the selection list can be used in the `HAVING` clause

Comment: should be `GROUP BY U.UserID`; it's almost never a good idea to group by names instead of ids; as is, this query would: erroneously include one row for two users with the same name who each paid 25000, and only include one listing for two users with the same name who each paid over 40000.

Comment: (or `GROUP BY U.UserID, U.Name` if using a version that doesn't exempt functionally dependencies from only_full_group_by restrictions)

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing columns that don't exist in the tables you specify. The `Order` table doesn't have `CarID` or `amountOfCars`. Those are in `CarOrders`, you have to join with that to relate orders with cars.

`ON c.UserID == c.UserID` makes no sense at all, that will always be true. You meant `ON Users.UserID = c.UserID`.

I recommend using aliases that are more mnemonic than `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. Abbreviations for the table names are better.

```
SELECT u.name
FROM Users AS u
JOIN (
    SELECT o.UserID
    FROM Orders AS o
    JOIN CarOrders AS co ON co.OrderID = o.OrderID
    JOIN Cars AS c on co.CarID = c.CarID
    GROUP BY o.UserID
    HAVING SUM(co.amountOfCars * c.Price) > 40000
) AS o ON o.UserID = u.UserID
```